# Oracle SQL get count and rows in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't figure out if is possible to get a count while also returning the rows in a single query.

an example would be:

```
select * 
from foo
  join ...
where ...
order by some_column
offset 0 rows fetch next 50 rows only
```

So what i would like, is to get the count before the fetch, and save it to an output variable in my procedure.
So that when i call my procedure I would get my cursor and a the count.

Is it possible to do that in a single query without having to call it for a count and then another time just to fetch the rows for my cursor?

I hope the example is good enough as i can't provide any direct use case due to confidential information.

Comment: Probably you need `count(*) over ()`. Please read [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/count-analytic-function).

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE ...
ORDER BY some_row
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT (SELECT count(*) FROM some_table) ROWS ONLY;
```